# What do you think of Google's new programming language: Noop?

Tags: programming-languages, no-op

http://code.google.com/p/noop/

> Noop (pronounced noh-awp, like the machine instruction) is a new language that attempts to blend the best lessons of languages old and new, while syntactically encouraging industry best-practices and discouraging the worst offenses. Noop is initially targeted to run on the Java Virtual Machine.

What's the pros/cons with using this language?

Comment: What, another language based on all the prior languages, but this time they've got it right? Now how many times have I heard that one before?

Comment: What makes you think this language comes from Google? I can't find anything on the page that would suggest that. It just looks like these fellows are hosting their project on Google Code.

Comment: Chris, the one of those two who is capable of maintaining his page and not let the world know only about database connection is google employee.

Comment: @Chris Bunch It is indeed coming from Google. http://www.channelregister.co.uk/2009/09/17/google_noop/

Comment: i had been searching for noop since morning on SOFlow .. did not occur to me that it was simply too new for even SOFlow!

Answer (score 5):

When reading the linked page I was hoping to find the *April, 1st* date somewhere. Alas.

Comment: Yeah. Why else would they name a language after something that does nothing? "Hey, I've just made a new language. I shall call it *Couch Potato*!"

Comment: mmyers, yes, but it's not only in the name, but in more or less all traits they seem to proud of.

Comment: Because the Highest Doing is Doing Nothing.  It's Taoism guys :)

Comment: GordonG, good point. ;-) That makes *the name* better. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

From the [news stories](http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/google-noop-project-features-jvm-based-language-198) I've seen, Noop (pronouced *noh-awp*) is a **very new** programming language.

I checked out its [code base](https://noop.googlecode.com/hg/) (Hg) and you can see it is only a month old.  From its site, its clear that this language is more in the brainstorming and trying stuff out stage rather than the developing towards a release date stage.  And certainly not in the showing off what amazing things can be done stage.

I'd say were months early in evaluating this language.  It may not materialize at all and if so, it may never be adopted within Google at all.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like an official Google project. It is just hosted at Google Code.

The project seems as if it is in a very early stage, so it is hard to tell whether or not the language will be any good.

Judging only by the tone of the writing on the project page and the proposed features, I would say that the target audience seems to be enterprise programmers. Whether or not the language will be a *good* enterprise language remains to be seen.

I don't think I will be learning it any time soon though. I usually stick to language on the "mainstream fringe", such as Haskell or F#. There are way too many half-baked languages out there to even bother. But that's just me.

Comment: yes, the praise sounds very enterprisey.

Comment: funny, how I was willing to give it the benefit of the doubt when I thought that google was doing it - and now I am not.

Answer (score 0):

I like the ideas proposed to date a lot. The goal is to make a better Java, especially more immutable and more functional, but without introduction of much more new features like in Scala. A bit like a cleaned up Java.

The goals and ideas probably are grown out of the use of Java inside Google and the lack of development of the Java language.

However, development is very early and the development of a languages takes much time. I personally doubt that Noop will find much adaption.

Answer (score 0):

Meh, Let them get a working product out first.